# Modifying the Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu screen

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, ubiquity

I'm creating a respin based on Ubuntu and when I install on BIOS I get the familiar Try/Install screen. This is fine except that I'd like to change the text that shows up on that screen. Instead of saying "Try Ubuntu" I'd like it to say "Try XYZ". I know this is possible since it says "Try Xubuntu" on a Xubuntu install.

Where can I find this text so I can change it? I've been looking all through the ISO and it doesn't seem to be anywhere.